# Why won't the file uploaded get sent to the database via post request?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

Upon the user submitting which picture of their choosing, I'd like to know why it won't get sent to the database upon form submission.  I believe my Models and Controller are a bit off, namely in the `PostPicturesController.php` file, where `body` might be causing the issue, but I could be dead wrong.  How can I fix this and make user chosen file get sent to the database upon form submission.  Pastebins provided below.

I get a quick error in the console but it disappears real quick upon clicking Submit so it's kind of hard to catch it but what I do see is POST with red background for a split second in red indicating an error so it might have something to do with `axios.post` in my react.js code.

https://pastebin.com/eyzT7kXH (Laravel code models, controller, web.php)
https://pastebin.com/EMwmAdJU (react.js code, method and JSX to handle post request)

Error I'm getting in the console:

```
POST http://my_website.test/home 500 (Internal Server Error)
Here's the error Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

Error I'm getting in the logs:

```
[2019-09-14 21:23:38] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::postPictures() 
{"userId":5,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): 
Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\BelongsTo::postPictures()
```

Comment: `I get a quick error in the console but it disappears real quick upon clicking Submit` enable "Persist Log" (or "preserve log" in Chrom and Edge), a submit loads a new page, persistent logs means the log wont clear on loading a new page - then you'll have the error in full view

Comment: If I remember correctly (been years since I bothered with PHP) ... when uploading files to PHP, one uses the global `$_FILES` - no evidence of that in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX error posted in my original post, thanks for showing me that sir.

Comment: error 500 - the issue is with server side code - check the server php logs for the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

many issues would cause Internal Server Error (500)

add this line to your .htaccess file to trace those errors

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

and this one to top of your PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with method chaining. I think the way you're chaining these methods `$postPicture->user()->postPictures()` is causing unexpected behavior because `user` is returning an instance of the belongs to relation itself not the user object, which actually has the `postPictures` method.

Edit: You need to call `get` to get the related data, not just the relation itself, i.e. `$postPicture->user()->get()`. This should return the user object which has the `postPictures` method.

Relevant source code:
[Model::belongsTo](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L170) and
[Relation::get](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php#L153)

Comment: Updated my answer, see links to source code above for relevant function signatures.